# Ошибка при инициализации shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointer

Почему это не работает:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> a = new int;
```

В то время как это работает:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> a(new int);
```

В первом случае компилятор выдает ошибку

```
conversion from ‘int*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<int>’ requested
```

В обоих случаях создается shared_ptr от new int, каким образом отличются эти два вида инициализации, мне казалось, что это одно и то же, в обоих случаях просто вызывается конструктор

`shared_ptr<T>(T*);`

Но похоже, что это не так

Answer (score 2):

Это разные виды инициализации: copy и direct.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization.

В первом случае рассматриваются только не `explicit` варианты, но у `shared_ptr` таких нет.